# HTTP Error 403.14 – Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing an error of  "HTTP Error 403.14 – Forbidden" 
Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

on VS 2012 with ISS 8.8

Comment: Is this a MVC project?

Comment: Yes MVC 4 application

Comment: And what is your question? Where are you encountering this, and why does the text of the error not help you understand the situation?

Comment: I am asking the solution of this error and facing it while running my MVC 4.0 application on visual studio 2012

Comment: Best practice: When faced with a HTTP status on IIS like this, look up the error message in the IIS W3C log files. There will be also a Win32 status column (simply a Win32 error code), which often provides helpful information.

Comment: In order for us to help with your problem, you need to provide us as much information as possible. Remember that we can't see your application, or know what you've tried so far. Is it happening on every part of your project, or one section? Did you just start the project from scratch, and get this error immediately, or did you change something that made it happen? What kind of settings have you applied? What output were you expecting to see? What does the URL look like that you're accessing? Note that these are just sample questions to get you started, not a complete checklist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated this was a MVC project you can try this. All you need to do is add this to your web.config or modify the section modules if you already have it.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    ...
<system.webServer>
```